# MongoDB - Sharding migrateThread long running since 3 hours

Tags: mongodb, sharding

MongoDB Version: 3.0.8
Engine: WiredTiger

The Balancer is too slow to migrate ~30MB chucks, Due to that we observed long running queries, that's stating that its been running more than 3 hours. Please suggest me.

Attached the long running output from db.currentOp().
Thank You,
Albert

```
------ Long Running Query ----

{
    "desc" : "migrateThread",
    "threadId" : "0x95d26a000",
    "opid" : "u001b_s2_rs:-1345098410",
    "active" : true,
    "secs_running" : 9360,
    "microsecs_running" : NumberLong("9360370895"),
    "op" : "none",
    "ns" : "deviceStateEvent.deviceStateEvent",
    "query" : {

    },
    "msg" : "step 2 of 5",
    "numYields" : 0,
    "locks" : {

    },
    "waitingForLock" : false,
    "lockStats" : {
        "Global" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(126582),
                "w" : NumberLong(126580)
            }
        },
        "Database" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(1),
                "w" : NumberLong(126579),
                "W" : NumberLong(1)
            }
        },
        "Collection" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(1),
                "w" : NumberLong(63290),
                "W" : NumberLong(1)
            }
        },
        "oplog" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "w" : NumberLong(63288)
            }
        }
    }
}

{
    "desc" : "conn514744",
    "threadId" : "0x4423e3400",
    "connectionId" : 514744,
    "opid" : "u001b_s0_rs:2109828171",
    "active" : true,
    "secs_running" : 9360,
    "microsecs_running" : NumberLong("9360954810"),
    "op" : "query",
    "ns" : "deviceStateEvent.deviceStateEvent",
    "query" : {
        "$msg" : "query not recording (too large)"
    },
    "client_s" : "10.99.8.121:45784",
    "msg" : "step 3 of 6",
    "numYields" : 1063,
    "locks" : {

    },
    "waitingForLock" : false,
    "lockStats" : {
        "Global" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(2130),
                "w" : NumberLong(1),
                "R" : NumberLong(1)
            }
        },
        "Database" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(1064),
                "w" : NumberLong(1)
            }
        },
        "Collection" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(1064),
                "W" : NumberLong(1)
            }
        }
    }   

------- Balancer Error -----------

balancer:
        Currently enabled:  no
        Currently running:  no
        Failed balancer rounds in last 5 attempts:  0
        Migration Results for the last 24 hours:
                116 : Success
                1 : Failed with error 'chunk too big to move', from u001b_s4_rs to u001b_s3_rs
                9 : Failed with error 'moveChunk failed to engage TO-shard in the data transfer: can't accept new chunks because  there are still 7 deletes from previous migration', from u001b_s2_rs to u001b_s4_rs
                402 : Failed with error 'data transfer error', from u001b_s0_rs to u001b_s3_rs
                322 : Failed with error 'moveChunk failed to engage TO-shard in the data transfer: can't accept new chunks because  there are still 6 deletes from previous migration', from u001b_s2_rs to u001b_s4_rs
                8 : Failed with error 'moveChunk failed to engage TO-shard in the data transfer: can't accept new chunks because  there are still 7 deletes from previous migration', from u001b_s0_rs to u001b_s4_rs
                6 : Failed with error 'moveChunk failed to engage TO-shard in the data transfer: can't accept new chunks because  there are still 8 deletes from previous migration', from u001b_s0_rs to u001b_s4_rs
                1 : Failed with error 'moveChunk failed to engage TO-shard in the data transfer: can't accept new chunks because  there are still 8 deletes from previous migration', from u001b_s1_rs to u001b_s4_rs
                1 : Failed with error 'chunk too big to move', from u001b_s4_rs to u001b_s1_rs
                2 : Failed with error 'moveChunk failed to engage TO-shard in the data transfer: can't accept new chunks because  there are still 7 deletes from previous migration', from u001b_s1_rs to u001b_s4_rs
                387 : Failed with error 'moveChunk failed to engage TO-shard in the data transfer: can't accept new chunks because  there are still 6 deletes from previous migration', from u001b_s0_rs to u001b_s4_rs
                35 : Failed with error 'moveChunk failed to engage TO-shard in the data transfer: can't accept new chunks because  there are still 2 deletes from previous migration', from u001b_s0_rs to u001b_s2_rs
                15 : Failed with error 'chunk too big to move', from u001b_s0_rs to u001b_s3_rs
                2 : Failed with error 'chunk too big to move', from u001b_s0_rs to u001b_s2_rs
                192 : Failed with error 'moveChunk failed to engage TO-shard in the data transfer: can't accept new chunks because  there are still 6 deletes from previous migration', from u001b_s1_rs to u001b_s4_rs
                23 : Failed with error 'chunk too big to move', from u001b_s0_rs to u001b_s1_rs
                5 : Failed with error 'moveChunk failed to engage TO-shard in the data transfer: can't accept new chunks because  there are still 8 deletes from previous migration', from u001b_s2_rs to u001b_s4_rs
                77 : Failed with error 'moveChunk failed to engage TO-shard in the data transfer: can't accept new chunks because  there are still 1 deletes from previous migration', from u001b_s0_rs to u001b_s2_rs
```

Comment: Did this issue get solved for you? If so, how? I think the issue that we have right now is very similar. And because of this, we can't write the map-reduced statistics into the collection.

Answer (score 0):

There are some deletes are remaining so it isn't accepting new chunks.

First you need to enable you balancer : 
   Go to mongos and run `sh.setBalancerState(true)`

This might work for you

1. Go to shard : u001b_s4_rs
2. go to mongo console and step down your primary node.

   `rs.stepDown()`

and check status again.